# Undefined reference to function never used/defined/anything?

Tags: c

I have a C function as follows:

```
static uint32_t initrd_read(fs_node_t *node, 
    uint32_t offset, uint32_t size, uint8_t *buffer) {

    initrd_file_header_t header = file_headers[node->inode];
    if (offset > header.length)
        return 0;
    if (offset+size > header.length)
        size = header.length-offset;
    memcopy(buffer, header.offset+offset, size);
    return size;
}
```

When linked with the rest of the program, an `undefined reference to 'memcpy'` is thrown. `memcpy` is never used in the code, and is not defined. The code is linked free-standing, so it is not conflicting with a C library. For some reason the linker thinks that the above function is calling `memcpy` at the beginning of the function call, and I'm not sure why.

Why could this be happening?

Comment: I suggest disassemble the target file and see where `memcpy` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memcpy` could be used implicitly by the compiler to perform "long" copying operations (like struct assignment). For example, in your code you are doing

```
initrd_file_header_t header = file_headers[node->inode];
```

which looks like a good candidate for something that will actually be translated into an `memcpy` call.

Is there a reason you create a copy of that `initrd_file_header_t` object instead of accessing the original directly? I don't see you modify that object, so you could just do

```
const initrd_file_header_t *header = &file_headers[node->inode];
```

and access the fields as `header->length` etc. That probably will eliminate that implicit call to `memcpy`.

Comment: Didn't consider long copies. Thanks! (will select the answer when it opens in 5 mins)